# Syncing remote MySQL database with localhost from the first inserted records with MySQL Replication

Tags: mysql, replication, database-replication

I have a database **myDB** in the remote server (master) which has a table **myTBL** with some records. I want to sync the remote database with my localhost (slave) using *MySQL Replication*. So I have created the replication user in master and also a database with the name of **myDB** and the **myTBL** table in the localhost.

I want to use GTIDs method to syncing my databases because there is a description in MySQL website as follows:

> MySQL 8.0 supports different methods of replication. The traditional
>   method is based on replicating events from the master's binary log,
>   and requires the log files and positions in them to be synchronized
>   between master and slave. The newer method based on global transaction
>   identifiers (GTIDs) is transactional and therefore does not require
>   working with log files or positions within these files, which greatly
>   simplifies many common replication tasks.

My master MySQL *mysqld.cnf* has:

```
server_id=1
enforce_gtid_consistency = on
gtid_mode = on
log_bin
log_slave_updates
```

and the status is:

```
             File: ***-bin.000001
         Position: 314969
     Binlog_Do_DB: 
 Binlog_Ignore_DB: 
Executed_Gtid_Set: 9a670a45-be0a-11e9-be56-52540055d8e4:1-368
```

and my salve *mysqld.cnf* has:

```
server-id = 2
read_only = 1
gtid_mode=ON
enforce-gtid-consistency=ON
skip-slave-start=ON
```

and I use the following commands to start syncing in slave:

```
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='***', MASTER_USER='***', MASTER_PASSWORD='***', MASTER_AUTO_POSITION=1; 
start slave;
```

And every thing is OK with this status in slave:

```
...
     Slave_IO_Running: Yes
    Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
...
```

So, every new record that inserted to master database is synced with my slave (localhost) database. But the records which are inserted before syncing do not placed in localhost. How can I sync them? Or in the other words, How do I start syncing from the first records? (I saw in some websites which proposed using mysqldump to dump the first data, is there a better way?)